# Ember sorting/filter table

Tags: sorting, ember.js

I am looking to add a filter/sorter table into the application. I need to choose which column can be sorted - and provide change of class glyphs up/down arrows on the columns. The filter box also needs to be outside of the table.

- I tried looking at this example, but there are no glyph class changes on the cols and the filter box is inside the table.

http://crodriguez1a.github.io/ember-sort-filter-table/

- I looked at this custom solution, but I couldn't see a way of locking the filter to specific cols.

http://www.jarrodctaylor.com/posts/Filter-And-Sort-Tables-In-Ember/
http://emberjs.jsbin.com/yezonaxu/12/edit?html,css,js,output

---

what about this one -- http://onechiporenko.github.io/ember-models-table/v.2/docs/classes/Components.ModelsTableRowFiltering.html

but the problem here - is how to create some custom markup depending on the data.

Answer (score 0):

You could sort and filter your rows using computed properties. For sorting you could use [`sort`](https://emberjs.com/api/ember/3.2/functions/@ember%2Fobject%2Fcomputed/sort) macro. For filter you should implement your own logic, cause `filter` and `filterBy` macros does not support observing a value used to filter the array. Use the sorted and filtered rows to generate a simple HTML table or pass it to a [table component of your choice](https://emberobserver.com/categories/lists-and-tables).

Answer (score 0):

If you will take [DataTables](https://datatables.net/) and wrap it in ember component (custom code would work better that some generalized 3rd-party wrapper), you can achieve a lot. Including filtering by columns. It's a bit hard way, though - DataTables is big and it's API is a bit complicated. That's if you want client-side filtering.

For server-side filtering approach would be different - you render UI for filters using ember's methods, convert user's choices to string and pass that to API (which should be modified to support filtering) when asking for data.

Comment: what about this one -- http://onechiporenko.github.io/ember-models-table/v.2/docs/classes/Components.ModelsTableRowFiltering.html

Comment: @TheOldCounty Looks good but I didn't work with it, so can't say more